# Is it possible to capture part of the URL as data in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have a `docs` collection and I have urls like this:

```
/docs/latest
/docs/latest/installation/
/docs/latest/quickstart/ 
/docs/v0.0.27
/docs/v0.0.27/installation/
/docs/v0.0.27/quickstart/
```

I'd like to be able to identify the `latest` vs `v0.0.27` part without having to use frontmatter on each page to specify it. Is this possible?